# Django - 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

So I've been struggling super hard with implementing special offers to my site. I have compared code to working code and tried to recreate some functionality but it's just not working and I really need a hand. I'm very tired now and if anyone can spot it or point me in the right direction I will be eternally grateful. Apologies for the formatting. I have pasted 2 sections of the HTML that are relevent to Categories and Special Offers. The Categories works perfectly, when I access this a categories URL for something it works fine, if I access a Special Offer URL it doesn't work. I want each item to be able to have a Category and/or a Special Offer. This will allow me to link to specific special offer categories and so on. I will paste the full traceback at the bottom. Anyone have any ideas?

Links ( elements) I'm using:

```
<a href="{% url 'products' %}?category=acoustic-drumkits" class="dropdown-item">Drumkits</a>

<a href="{% url 'products' %}?special_offers=clearance" class="dropdown-item ">B Stock</a>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Model for Categories
    """
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_friendly_name(self):
        return self.friendly_name


class SpecialOffers(models.Model):
    """
    Model for Special Offers
    """

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Special Offers"
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_friendly_name(self):
        return self.friendly_name


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    description = models.TextField()
    product_dimensions = models.TextField(blank=True)
    additional_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_images/", null=True, blank=True)
    # Product Sales
    on_sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    out_of_stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    b_stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    new_product = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    special_offers = models.ForeignKey(
        'SpecialOffers', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def all_products(request):
    """ 
    A view to show all products, including sorting and search queries 
    """

    products = Product.objects.all()
    query = None
    categories = None
    sort = None
    direction = None
    special_offers = None

    if request.GET:
        if 'sort' in request.GET:
            sortkey = request.GET['sort']
            sort = sortkey
            if sortkey == 'name':
                sortkey = 'lower_name'
                products = products.annotate(lower_name=Lower('name'))
            if sortkey == 'category':
                sortkey = 'category__name'
            if sortkey == 'special_offers':
                sortkey = 'special_offers__name'
            if 'direction' in request.GET:
                direction = request.GET['direction']
                if direction == 'desc':
                    sortkey = f'-{sortkey}'
            products = products.order_by(sortkey)

        if 'category' in request.GET:
            categories = request.GET['category'].split(',')
            products = products.filter(category__name__in=categories)
            categories = Category.objects.filter(name__in=categories)
    
        if 'special_offers' in request.GET:
            speical_offers = request.GET['special_offers'].split(',')
            products = products.filter(special_offers__name__in=special_offers)
            special_offers = SpecialOffers.objects.filter(name__in=special_offers)

    if request.GET:
        if 'q' in request.GET:
            query = request.GET['q']
            if not query:
                messages.error(request, "You didn't enter a search criteria")
                return redirect(reverse('products'))
            
            queries = Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)
            products = products.filter(queries)

    current_sorting = f'{sort}_{direction}'

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'search_term': query,
        'current_categories': categories,
        'current_sorting': current_sorting,
        'current_special_offers': special_offers,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center mt-3">
                <h2 class="logo-font">Products</h2>
                {% for c in current_categories %}
                    <a class="category-badge text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ c.name }}">
                        <span class="p-2 mt-2 badge badge-white text-black rounded-0 border border-dark">{{ c.friendly_name }}</span>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
                {% for c in current_special_offers %}
                    <a class="category-badge text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'products' %}?special_offers={{ c.name }}">
                        <span class="p-2 mt-2 badge badge-white text-black rounded-0 border border-dark">{{ c.friendly_name }}</span>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
                <hr class="w-50 mb-1">
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- More HTML Code for Categories / Special Offers -->

 <!-- Check for Product Image, display NoImage if no Product Image added. -->
{% if product.image %}
    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
    </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png" alt="{{ product.name }}">
    </a>
{% endif %}
<div class="card-body pb-0">
    <p class="mb-0">{{ product.name }}</p>
</div>
<div class="card-footer bg-white pt-0 border-0 text-left">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="lead mb-0 text-left fw-light"><strike class="text-orange">${{ product.price }}</strike>
                <span class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold">${{ product.sale_price }}</span>
            </p>
            <!-- Check for product category -->
            {% if product.category %}
            <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ product.category.name }}">
                    <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1"></i>{{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                </a>
            </p>
            {% endif %}
            <!-- Check for Special Offers -->
            {% if product.special_offers %}
            <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'products' %}?speical_offers={{ product.special_offers.name }}">
                    <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1"></i>{{ product.special_offers.friendly_name }}
                </a>
            </p>
            {% endif %}
```

Traceback error:

```
[08/Dec/2023 20:29:15] "GET /products/?special_offers=clearance HTTP/1.1" 500 123780
Internal Server Error: /products/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Portfolio_Project5/products/views.py", line 45, in all_products
    products = products.filter(special_offers__name__in=special_offers)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1416, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1435, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1370, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1216, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 234, in get_prep_lookup
    for rhs_value in self.rhs:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Any time you get a NoneType error, you should look for the function call that returned a None you didn't expect.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback

Comment: @MarkRansom I have just added an update to the main post. Looks like I never called the context for current_special_offers, so you put me on the right track. I decided to create a new template page under my includes folder. But I'm getting a templatedoesnotexist error. I've done this with the footer, head etc and it works fine.

Any ideas? Tracebook at the end of my updated post.

Comment: @Tarquinius Someone else mentioned a function call, looks like I wasn't calling it. I've added a new HTML page to compensate for this but now getting a TemplateDoesNotExist error, traceback in the updated post (at the bottom). I also posted the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as I realised in the end it was a typo in my 'special_offers' variable. 'speical_offers' - Embarassing. Learn from me, copy paste and always check that your variable names are correct.